# Regex must not start with 0 but can start with 0. or 0,

Tags: regex, floating-point

I've been trying make a reg exp that accept

```
0.27878
0,8989
2.98889
```

But must not start with only `0` such as `088989383`.

I've used  `^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:(\.|,)\d+)?$`.

Any solutions .. thanks

Comment: Yes allowed is 

2.3903093 and 
29034  , 0.33323 , 0,333 
Not allowed:  2. ,  078778

Comment: Use [`^(?!0+[1-9])(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:(\.|,)\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/lMB2R1/2). The `(?!0+[1-9])` negative lookahead will fail all strings starting with 1 or more zeros followed with a digit other than `0`.

Comment: @wiktorStribizew .. Thanks for solution. Its working now

Comment: Is `00.123` allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!0+[1-9])(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:[.,]\d+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lMB2R1/3). The `(?!0+[1-9])` negative lookahead will fail all strings starting with 1 or more zeros followed with a digit other than `0`.

If you want to fail `00.825` like numbers, replace the lookahead with `(?!0\d)`:

```
^(?!0\d)(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:[.,]\d+)?$
```

See the [pattern variation demo](https://regex101.com/r/lMB2R1/4).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0+[1-9])` - a negative lookahead failing the strings that start with 1 or more zeros followed with a digit other than `0` (or `(?!0\d)` will fail all cases when a number starts with a `0` followed with any digit)
- `(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)` - two alternatives:

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
  - `(?:,\d{3})+` - 1 or more consecutive occurrences of `,` and then any 3 digits
- `(?:[.,]\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` or `,` and then 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.